# How android ART may affect apps which are using obfuscators like proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-5.0-lollipop

In Android 5.0, Google introduced ART. In its API changes [documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#ART) it is mentioned that apps which are using obfuscators like proguard need to pay attention. But no other detail is given. Does anyone know how ART can affect proguard enabled apps and what can be its impact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "But no other detail is given" -- yes, [there is](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html#AOT_Fails): "ART does tighter bytecode verification at install time than Dalvik does. Code produced by the Android build tools should be fine. However, some post-processing tools (especially tools that perform obfuscation) may produce invalid files that are tolerated by Dalvik but rejected by ART. We have been working with tool vendors to find and fix such issues. In many cases, getting the latest versions of your tools and regenerating the DEX files can fix these problems."

Comment: @CommonsWare, Google should add direct link to such information. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Google do not mention ProGuard, they only speak about "some obfuscators". AFAIK ProGuard's obfuscation technique is so "leightweight" that it will not be affected by ART.

I assume Google is referring to obfuscators that build Java byte code dynamically at run-time in memory (which is not done by ProGuard).